# Visual Basic 6.0 Inbox formatting input

Tags: vb6

In my new project I need to format the outcome from the Inputbox going to TextBox.The Input are the numbers from 1 to 9.My input into the Inputbox looks like: exp... 123 OK, 234 OK, 456 OK...and so and so, NO SPACE.There will be a lot of numbers to manually enter. Those numbers later will be stored and will be occasionally added and processed for the highest number, and number of multiple repeats. This part I have already lined up.The TexBox must look: each line of 3 numbers separated
by spase with single vbnewline:

> 1 2 3
>
> 2 3 4
>
> 5 6 7

I try to achieve this with this simple code, but that idea does not work:

```
For i = 1 To a
   ans = InputBox(".........")

   If ans = "" Then
      Exit Sub
   Else
      For b = 1 To 3
         Inp = Inp & Mid$(ans, b, 1) & " "
      Next

      Text1.Text = Inp & vbCrLf    ' or vbnewLine

   End if

Next
```

From all of this I am getting:  1 2 3 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9...etc... no vbnewline

Any help in the matter would be much appreciated.

I did not get what I was looking for.

Comment: Your Text1 textbox Multiline property should be set to True otherwise the text will stay on one line even if the text has inline VbCrLf characters in it.

Comment: Oh, yes.. it does. I have set to multilines. ( forgot to mention that )

Comment: Works for me! - I tried it before posting to check. Set Multiline to False and the string is all on one line. Set it to True and your string is displayed as seperate lines of 3 characters.

Comment: Hello John, Thanks for the reply.
I have tried all possible codes, ( having over 10 years break from programming in VB 6.0) and so far nothing works for me. I also try using single line setup
and force newline, also with no success. 
Did you use my code, or did you come with a different one ? 
Perhaps I am missing something here ?
I can not go forward until I solve ( possibly with help ) this annoying issue.

Comment: What if the user enter fewer than 3 digits, or more than 3 digits?...

Comment: The user is me for time being, but I must add that prtection in case if the entry numbers are messed up, becouse it will create a mess during number sort

Comment: To be honest I did just use a single string with newline characters in it rather than your code. Didn't realise there was a problem in the code itself. It is a long time since I last fired up VB6, but I'd been using it since the days of VB3.

Comment: Good thinking..The user is me for the time being, but I must add that protection in case if the entry numbers are messed up, because it will create a mess during number sorting for repeating and calculation,  looking for the numbers of highest repeated numbers in the data. That part I am working on, I will add 4 numbers as data entry and 5 numbers as well. I just discovered that in my code I have one ( not needed ) space after each line. Must  do something about this now, another head scratcher.

Comment: John, I did not get  your  idea about use a single string with newline characters.Do you mean that my code is not sufficient for entry ? For the further calculation,  I must use this entry format, part I already worked on.This thing all of a sudden becomes more difficult and complicated as I progress.By the way, so far  I see all the codes VB6 are compatible with Win-11.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using the newer VB.Net and Visual Studio for a NEW PROJECT? It's FREE. You could do this quite easily in a VB.Net WinForms project and take advantage of the new functionality given to you in the .Net Framework...

Comment: Before I retired  about 10 years ago, I was using VB6 a lot
generally  programming communication using Ports Com1/Com2.. for remotely
controlling CCTV  composite Video, typical types these days,  
using this for all Domes cameras, Multiplexers, Vicon and Pelco ( you might remember those ). It was fun doing this.
Since I retired I left programming for this period of time, and now I have some urge
to get back into this in the evening time. Getting into VB NET, this opens totally a new horizon and would take me a time to get acquainted with new codes.

Comment: Well, welcome back! Definitely give Visual Studio and VB.Net a try. WinForms is closest to the VB6. You'll pick it up....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked your code a little bit to achieve the desired results:

```
For i = 1 To a
   ans = InputBox(".........")
 
   If ans = "" Then Exit Sub
      
   Inp = ""
   
   For b = 1 To 3
      Inp = Inp & Mid$(ans, b, 1) & " "
   Next

   Text1.Text = Text1.Text & Inp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next
```

However, this can be done more simply using the Format command:

```
For i = 1 To a
   ans = InputBox(".........")
   
   If ans = "" Then Exit Sub
      
   Text1.Text = Text1.Text & Format(ans, "@ @ @") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next
```

Comment: So well done, so little changed. Works like a charm. Thanks John, much appreciated. I used only a single newline as the forum's message did not take a single new line when showing you the proper numbers. This whole exercise allows me to enter a bunch of numbers in a fast way, omitting spaces between the entering numbers manually.  Thanks again.

Comment: @rpmax it was Brian, not John :)  And since that worked for you, click the "accept" button.

Comment: OK, How do I change the name in  this " thank you " reply and apologies to Brian ?
I confused there 2 names., and where can I find this " accept " button ?

Comment: The "accept" button should be a check mark next to the answer. And no worries @rpmax about the name confusion. I knew what you meant.

Comment: OK, Done, I am a new member, I do have one more question.I would like to continue conversation with Brian and I do not see a button  to open further communication with him following my thanks message.This would include sending him a screen picture and asking for suggestion.Please advice.

Comment: OK seems  duigital OK

Comment: @rpmax If you have a specific question about a portion of your project I would recommend asking another, separate question including the relevant code.